# Can I send interactive messages with Call-to-Action buttons without having to create my own message template? Whatsapp cloud API

Tags: javascript, node.js, whatsapp-cloud-api

```
{
        "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
        "recipient_type": "individual",
        "to": "MO_NUMBER",
        "type": "interactive",
        "interactive": {
          "type": "button",
          "body": {
              "text":"this is the message"
          }, 
                
          "action": {
              "buttons": [
                  {
                      "type": "reply",
                      "reply": {
                          "id": "UNIQUE_BUTTON_ID_1",
                          "title": "reply"
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      "type": "reply",
                      "reply": {
                          "id": "UNIQUE_BUTTON_ID_2",
                          "title": "call"
                      }
                  }
              ]
          }
      }
    }
```

Trying to add a Call to Action Button instead of a call to reply